# Why does my PHP code pass through to my browser? info.php looks like a blank page

Tags: php, nginx, configuration

In Ubuntu, I installed nginx, php5, php5-fpm and the default info.php showed the info fine.

I had some adventures with trying to get the correct user name and permissions on my files when I moved them to /usr/share, but I think I got that part set up OK.

Now my browser if I "view source", I see the PHP code from info.php

```
<? echo phpinfo() ?>
```

What could be a likely cause for this?

Here's my sites-available config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysitefiles/web;
        index index.php index.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

Comment: Short tags may be disabled. Change it to <?php phpinfo(); ?> instead and see if that works.

Comment: It did! now what do i do?

Comment: Either change your PHP to use <?php tags instead of <? tags. Or enable php short tags in the php.ini file. Since short tags are deprecated, I'd suggest option number 1. But if you can't go through and change all the tags, then option number 2 works in a pinch.

Comment: Excellent, excellent .... i hope I can find the right php.ini file.  Thanks :)

Comment: In Ubuntu, in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, it has short_open_tag = Off (not in the same place as the comments) so I found it and changed it to On and did sudo service php5-fpm restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, in /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini, it has short_open_tag = Off (not in the same place as the comments.)

so I found it and changed it to On and did sudo service php5-fpm restart.

```
$sudo vim /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

...

```
$cat /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini | grep short_open_tag
short_open_tag = On
$sudo service php5-fpm restart
```